# Hide & Clear the TextBox when the checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

When i check the checkbox the textbox is displayed else it will be in hidden. But the value is not clearing. Help me someone. Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div class="munna">                    
    <input id="chk_1"  type="checkbox"  value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('cutting_price').focus();chk_box(this.id);"  onChange="chk_box(this.id)">Cutting
    <div id="chk_1_box" style="display:none ;">
        Price :<input type="text" value="" size="5"  name="cutting_price" id="cutting_price" onChange="post_production()" />            
    </div>
</div>

<div class="munna">                    
    <input id="chk_2"  type="checkbox"  value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('lamination_price').focus();chk_box(this.id);">Lamination
    <div id="chk_2_box" style="display:none;">
        Price :
        <input type="text" size="5" value=""  name="lamination_price" id="lamination_price" onChange="post_production()" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="munna">                    
    <input id="chk_3"  type="checkbox"  value="1" onChange="chk_box(this.id);" onClick="document.getElementById('die_making_price').focus();chk_box(this.id);">Die Making
    <div id="chk_3_box" style="display:none;">
        Price :
        <input type="text" size="5" value=""  name="die_making_price" id="die_making_price" onChange="post_production()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function chk_box(chk)
{
    if(document.getElementById(chk).checked)
    {
        var chk2 = chk+'_box';
        document.getElementById(chk2).style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        var chk2 = chk+'_box';
        document.getElementById(chk2).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById(chk2).value='';
    }
}
```

Comment: i created fiddle but cant see textbox http://jsfiddle.net/SBhNx/

Comment: May be a browser issue. Did you try using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the textbox element that is nested under `div`

modify your code to clear the value as

```
document.getElementById(chk2).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value='';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="munna">                    
<input id="chk_1"  type="checkbox"  value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('cutting_price').focus();" >Cutting
<div id="chk_1_box" style="display:none ;">
Price :<input type="text" value="" size="5"  name="cutting_price" id="cutting_price" onChange="post_production()" />            
</div>
</div>

<div class="munna">                    
<input id="chk_2"  type="checkbox"  value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('lamination_price').focus();">Lamination
<div id="chk_2_box" style="display:none;">
Price :
<input type="text" size="5" value=""  name="lamination_price" id="lamination_price" onChange="post_production()" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="munna">                    
<input id="chk_3"  type="checkbox"  value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('die_making_price').focus();">Die Making
<div id="chk_3_box" style="display:none;">
Price :
<input type="text" size="5" value=""  name="die_making_price" id="die_making_price" onChange="post_production()" />
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").show();
        }
        else{
          $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").find("input[type='text']").val("")  ;
          $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SBhNx/9/)

Comment: What if he's not using jQuery?

Comment: Said that, this thread has been tagged with jquery .. In fact jQuery script should be inserted somewhere ..

Comment: @PsychHalf check Demo

Comment: @AmitAgrawal sorry.. that was before you edited your answer....your very first one...

Comment: umm.. i guess you hadn't tested your first code cuz there was no Demo..  it's working great now :D

Comment: @AmitAgrawal i was just fiddling with your code and.. if we add $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").find("input[type='text']").focus() ; in if() statement...  we don't have to use document.getElementById in onclick.. full jQuery style... xD  http://jsfiddle.net/SBhNx/10/